# Invoke-Sqlcmd leaves script at 'PS SQLSERVER: \>' prompt

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd, powershell-cmdlet

I have a script that queries a MS SQL database as below:

```bsh
$query = "SELECT Path FROM repoLocations WHERE hostId = '$($hostId)'"
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $dbHost -Database $dbName -Username $dbUser -Password $dbPass -ErrorAction Stop
```

This works absolutely fine with one slight issue.  The first time the script is run, or indeed any script that uses `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, in a newly opened PowerShell console session, there is a delay of a few seconds, presumably where the module loads before completing.  The SQL query does work and always returns the correct result but on its first run, the prompt will be left at:

```
PS SQLSERVER: \>
```

Which then causes subsequent file operations to fail.

I have a workaround/solution, which is to add the following line of code immediately following the `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, which enables the script and prompt to work as expected everytime:

```bsh
$query = "SELECT Path FROM repoLocations WHERE hostId = '$($hostId)'"
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $dbHost -Database $dbName -Username $dbUser -Password $dbPass -ErrorAction Stop
Set-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot
```

As long as I used the same PowerShell session, the issue won't happen again and the pause before the SQL command is not present.

There are a number of other questions of similar topic that contain 'workarounds', but I'm curious as to whether there is a better fix, possibly to preload the SQL cmdlets at the start of the script before proceding?  If not, I will need to use `Set-Location` at every `Invoke-Sqlcmd` that could possibly be used by the script.

Comment: Just FYI, your query is very much open to a SQL injection attack.`$hostId = "Robert'; DROP TABLE students;-- ` https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Use the [`SqlServer`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.0.17199) module instead, the designated replacement of `SqlPs`, which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I didnt know of sqlserver being a replacement for sqlps and available from the powershell gallery.  This worked great thanks! Write it as an answer and I will mark as such.  Kind Rdgs, Rob.

Answer (score 4):

I had faced similar issue earlier. You are right. The path of the script changes to`PS SQLSERVER: \>` after an `Invoke-Sqlcmd` is executed. In my case, I had other operation too in the script which required the use of cmdlets like `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Content`. As expected, these commands didn't work because the path was not a `Windows Directory` path.

In such cases, I used `push-location` after `Invoke-Sqlcmd` like this

```
$query = "SELECT Path FROM repoLocations WHERE hostId = '$($hostId)'"
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $dbHost -Database $dbName -Username $dbUser -Password $dbPass -ErrorAction Stop
Push-Location -Path $env:USERPROFILE
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me! I used 'Push-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot' instead.

Comment: Thanks, people. Works like charm, saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

> possibly to preload the SQL cmdlets at the start of the script before proceding?

That's my solution.

```bsh
    try { Push-Location \ # importing sqlps switches you to the sql psdrive...
        Import-Module SQLPS
    } finally { Pop-Location }
```

The upside of this implementation is the script will `Pop-Location` you back to wherever you were.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I just hit the same issue today and found this question: the way I resolved was to install/import the SqlServer module, rather than using SQLPS and setting location on every DB query. That way $PWD remains unchanged after invoke-sqlcmd (PowerShell 5.1, SQL2017, Windows Server 2012)